# Seeking free tool to make choropleth map with administrative borders?

Tags: software-recommendations, choropleth, thematic-map

I have a numeric table for some [administrative division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division) like county, state, province, oblast.

Is there a free tool that I can supply with my table and get a choropleth map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/) and join it in QGIS with your data